# find condition that combine subdocument and document condition

Tags: mongodb

I have a subdocument "data" that is part of a larger document.  When I combine the subdocument condition with another condition I always get an empty result.  Each condition by itself returns the same 2 documents.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{ $and : [{ "data" : { "$elemMatch" : { "oid" : "1.3.6.1.4.1.111.3.5.11.5.32.1.15", 
                                        "value" : "1" }} }, 
          {"_id":{$in: [601, 1423]}}]}
```

Comment: any chance you could post a sample doc as well as the full query you are running?  makes debugging a lot easier

Comment: it works for me both this way and with , rather than $and.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem using MongoDB version 2.0.6. If you're interested in my pursuing this further, please post the following:

    - What version of MongoDB you're using
    - What language you're using to query (JavaScript, Python, Perl, etc.)?
    - The source code for the full find() commands that you're using for the two individual queries
    - The source code for the combined find() command that isn't returning your desired result

Having this information will give me a better chance of diagnosing your problem.